# how to time several background processes

Tags: time

I have a script `s`:

```
echo a &
echo b &
echo c &
```

Now I want to know how much time it will take for the script to finish.
I try

```
time bash s
```

But it gives me an immediate result which is not the correct one(my script is of course much more complicated than that I've written here and takes a lot of time)
How can I ask time to wait for all the subprocesses to finish.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `wait` to the very end of the script.  This will make the script wait for all background processes to exit before continuing.

The new script:

```
echo a &
echo b &
echo c &

wait
```